# SDN4 - Entity lifecycle event handlers compatible with GraphRepository

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE and would like to take advantage of the built-in data manipulation events to insert some audit information on the fly (e.g. timestamps).  [The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_data_manipulation_events_formerly_lifecycle_events) seems to suggest that this is only available to me if I am directly using `Neo4jTemplate`.

Are there any similar hooks available for the `GraphRepository` abstraction?  That is, is there an out of box way for me to hook into graph repository operations (a la Spring DataJPA?)  I've written some tests and can confirm that the documented events don't fire when I'm just using the `GraphRepository`.

Comment: Those hooks should also work with the repository as that internally uses a template.

Comment: Hmm I don't believe that's the case, at least based on what I see in the source code in `GraphRepositoryImpl`.  I have gotten around this for now by creating a custom aspect that intercepts calls to `GraphRepository.save(..)` and fires the data manipulation events.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking at then but [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/AbstractGraphRepository.java#L91) is clearly using a template... So not sure which implementation you are looking at.

Comment: Ah that one may be an older version? I am looking at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/GraphRepositoryImpl.java).  Again, I'm using 4.0.0.RELEASE; `AbstractGraphRepository` does not show up on my classpath.

Comment: Well that is the master I was looking at not a branche so it is actually the most recent version I would say :). So I would consider this an oversight/regression as compared to the other versions. Also not sure what the status of the 4.0 version is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractGraphRepository` is from the 3.x codebase, so is not directly relevant here.

As noted, SDN 4 does not yet provide automatic support for Spring's RepositoryEventListener interfaces. Implementing event listeners correctly in SDN 4.0 is complicated because of the nature of the underlying save mechanism, which persists an entire tree of "dirty" objects rather than just a single top-level entity. If the object you want to intercept is not the top-level entity being saved, the event listener for it won't fire.

The SDN development team is currently considering the best way to enable event handlers to fire for objects that may be persisted at any depth in the save tree.

In the meantime, the solution suggested by simonl should work.